# How to read PowerShell .PSD1 files safely

Tags: powershell

The PowerShell module manifest file format (.psd1) is essentially a Hashtable literal with certain keys expected. This is ideal for a configuration file for a PowerShell script. What I ultimately want to do is read a .psd1 file that contains a set of keys specific to the script.

For example (MyScriptConfig.psd1):

```
@{
    FTPHost = "ftp.blah.com"
    FTPUserName = "blah"
    FTPPassword = "blah"
}
```

There's no reason I can't use XML, INI, JSON or whatever for this information, but I'd rather it use the same basic data format as PowerShell's module manifests.

Obviously the easiest thing would be to read the text and pass it to `Invoke-Expression` which would return a Hashtable, but then it would invoke anything that's in the file, which is error prone and potentially unsafe.

I thought I recalled a cmdlet for reading this data using a "safe" subset of PowerShell cmdlets, but I was thinking of `ConvertFrom-StringData` and `DATA` sections, neither of which let me read an arbitrary file containing a Hashtable literal.

Is there something built into PowerShell that lets me do this? If there's nothing built in, then I would probably go the route of JSON or Key=Value with `ConvertFrom-StringData`.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Powershell version 5 added the Cmdlet [Import-PowershellDataFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-powershelldatafile) for safely parsing PSD1 files.

Prior to version 5, there were at least three solutions:

1. The Cmdlet [Import-LocalizedData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-localizeddata). Which, though intended for processing language files, will read any PSD1 formatted file.

   ```
   # Create a test PSD1 file
   @'
       @{
           a1 = 'a1'
           a2 = 2
           a3 = @{
             b1 = 'b1'
           }
       }
   '@ | Set-Content -Path .path\example.psd1

   # Read the file
   Import-LocalizedData -BaseDirectory .\path -FileName example.psd1 -BindingVariable Data

   # Use the data
   $Data.a1
   $Data.a3.b1
   ```
2. It is also possible to process in-line data with a [Data Section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_data_sections) (in-line sort of defeats the purpose).

   ```
   # Safely parse data
   $Data2 = DATA {
       @{
           a1 = 'a1'
           a2 = 2
           a3 = @{
             b1 = 'b1'
           }
       }
   }

   # Use the data
   $Data2.a1
   $Data2.a3.b1
   ```
3. The third being the [PowerShell DSC parameter transformation attribute mentioned by @Jakub Berezanski](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29423244/80161).

Answer (score 13):

PowerShell DSC defines a parameter transformation attribute, used to support passing a path to a .psd1 file as the value of the ConfigurationData parameter when invoking a Configuration. This attribute is public and can be used in a custom function, such as:

```
function Parse-Psd1
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [Microsoft.PowerShell.DesiredStateConfiguration.ArgumentToConfigurationDataTransformation()]
        [hashtable] $data
    )
    return $data
}
Parse-Psd1 C:\MyData.psd1
```

The attribute implementation calls an internal helper that evaluates the contents of the file in a restricted language context, where only the following cmdlets are permitted:

```
Import-LocalizedData
ConvertFrom-StringData
Write-Host
Out-Host
Join-Path
```

Answer (score 2):

Module manifests are specifically designed to use only a restricted subset of PSH, however there isn't<sup>1</sup> a direct way to process the content (and get all the data) in that mode. However you can validate a manifest with `Test-ModuleManifest`<sup>2</sup> and only then evaluate the contents of the file.

---

<sup>1</sup> At least as far as *PowerShell In Action* 2nd Ed covers it.

<sup>2</sup> Unfortunately the online copy of the book uses images for source code (to allow annotations), so can't copy here.