# Read an array from a file

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have an array stored in a file as follows :

```
  @(@(@("a","b"),@("aa","bb")),@(@("a","b"),@("a","b","c")))
```

When I try to read the file with:

```
 $var = Get-Content -Path  "PATH"
```

I got a string instead of a multiple array.

```
 $var.GetType
```

Returns :

```
 IsPublic IsSerial Name                      BaseType 
 -------- -------- ----                      --------
 True     True     String                    System.Object
```

How do I get `$var` as an array?

Comment: Can you give some context of what you are trying to achieve? Did you write the file yourself? What information are you storing inside of it?

Comment: Just use [PowerShell Dot-Sourcing](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts?view=powershell-7#script-scope-and-dot-sourcing): `$var = . C:\path\array.ps1`

Comment: If you are, say, saving configuration parameters, consider `Import-Clixml` and `Export-Clixml` cmdlets for a native Powershell object (de)serialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With invoke-Expression you can do it very easy.

```
$array_string = '@(@(@("a","b"),@("aa","bb")),@(@("a","b"),@("a","b","c")))'
$array = Invoke-Expression $array_string
$array.GetType() #System.Array
$array
```

invoke-Expression executes any string as powershell code.
But you should try to avoid using this, its a bad practice. Thats why i asked:

> can you give some context of what you are trying to achieve? Did you
>   write the file yourself? What information are you storing inside of
>   it?

Comment: I am trying to get informations from the array stored in the file . i want to do it directly no need to pass the infos and create the array myself

Answer (score 2):

Taken the fact that you want to retrieve from a file, you might simply use [PowerShell Dot-Sourcing](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts?view=powershell-7#script-scope-and-dot-sourcing):

```
$var = . .\array.ps1
```

<sub>(note that the extension has to be `.ps1`, otherwise is will start any application associated with the extension)</sub>

If you looking for [a safe way](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-security-best-practices/) to import the array, you might also use [`Import-LocalizedData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-localizeddata?view=powershell-7):

```
$var = Import-LocalizedData -FileName array.psd1
```

See also: [How to read PowerShell .PSD1 files safely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34144983/1701026)

Comment: I learned something new :) I was messing around a bit with this and it and i have some comments for @Ayoub: the extension had to be psd1 so he is going to need to rename his file first. Also it uses 2 params for the file -BaseDirectory and -FileName so you can not specify the full path in filename.